# Where does UiPath CE install to?

Tags: windows

Where does UiPath CE (Community Edition) install to? The installer doesn't create a Start menu or desktop shortcut.

So far I've looked in:

- `C:\Program Files`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It installs to `%localappdata%`:

```
%localappdata%\UiPath
```

Here's how the UiPath CE installer works as of April 2019 (version `19.4.2.0`):

- Doesn't create shortcuts
- Silently extracts
- Silently overwrites files (including settings)
- Silently launches UiPath

Again, the installer **silently overwrites your settings** if UiPath is already installed, so avoid rerunning it after installation.